# How can I simulate a rigid body bounced from a wall in 3D world?

Tags: physics, rigid-body-dynamics

How can I simulate a rigid sword bounced from a wall and hit the ground (like in physical world)?

I want to use this for a simple animation. I can detect the figure and the size of the sword (maybe needed in doing bounce). Rotation can be controlled by quaternions/matrix/euler angles. It should turn the head and do rotations and fly to the ground.

How can I simulate this physical process?

Maybe what I need is an equation and some parameters?

I need these data, and would combine them into my movie file, I use Mathematica to do the thing that generate the movie file(If I have the data, I can also export it into a 3DSMax script for example).

Comment: [This tutorial](http://gamedev.tutsplus.com/series/custom-game-physics-engine/) by Randy Gaul is amazing.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo Do you know how hard is it to create a Physics Engine? It seems a 2D engine.

Comment: Sorry, didn't read you wanted 3D. Anyway, it sounds like you want to create a physics engine (or you need to, to calculate those physical responses).

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to find yourself a physics engine. Since you're essentially asking how to create a physics engine. The equations and parameters you'd need are those of a collision detection and response system.

If it's just for a simple animation, you can fake it using techniques like [Rotoscoping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotoscoping) and [Onion Skinning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Onion_skinning) to create the animation from a video of a real object hitting a wall and falling.

Or you can use something like [Blender](http://www.blender.org/), which has a [physics engine](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Physics), to set up and create your animation.

Comment: well, the problem is I want to do this in Mathematica,,, seems no physics engine...Since I know little about other software, I know little about Blender(just know how to add position key...is it possible to simulate the process and export the data I needed into Mathematica?)

Comment: Exporting Blender into Mathematica is an entirely different question. It should be asked on the Blender stack exchange. If you're not open to using a physics engine, you need to create your own. That's collision detection and response. It's something that's far too broad to get anything more detailed than that here.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Mathematica, but if it can load external libraries you might be able to use the Bullet Physics (http://bulletphysics.org/).